# why spring cassandra query builder will execute many times?

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I just get the api once, but it will execute same Query 7 times
and took many time on duplicate query...

```
        @GetMapping(path = "/test")
        public void getSport() {
            Select navigation_competition_by_event_type = QueryBuilder
                    .select("event_id")
                    .from("navigation_competition_by_event_type");
            cassandraOperations.select(navigation_competition_by_event_type, Long.class);
        }

2018-07-24 12:40:27.533 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-1] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.8:9042] Query completed normally, took 1358 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:29.060 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-2] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.12:9042] Query completed normally, took 1047 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:30.681 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-3] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.10:9042] Query completed normally, took 1137 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:31.825 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-1] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.8:9042] Query completed normally, took 1131 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:32.596 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-2] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.12:9042] Query completed normally, took 759 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:33.228 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-3] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.10:9042] Query completed normally, took 620 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:34.083 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-1] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.8:9042] Query completed normally, took 840 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:34.937 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-2] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.12:9042] Query completed normally, took 839 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:35.741 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-3] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.10:9042] Query completed normally, took 792 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
2018-07-24 12:40:36.583 DEBUG 55608 --- [er-nio-worker-1] c.d.driver.core.QueryLogger.NORMAL       : [cluster] [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/ip.8:9042] Query completed normally, took 830 ms: SELECT event_id FROM navigation_competition_by_event_type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the logs I assume you are using multi-data center Cassandra cluster on a Kubernetes platform. 
I see 3 different ip addresses in the logs, so I guess you have a 3 DC cluster, most probably with 3 nodes each. You can confirm this with running nodetool status.

If so, I also assume, that your consistency level is set to QUORUM, so each node on each datacenter is queried - which might explain the 3 x 3 = 9 queries in the logs.

Comment: yes. we are using multi-data center Cassandra cluster on a Kubernetes platform

Comment: do you know how to fixes this? @andrea

Comment: cqlsh> CONSISTENCY;
Current consistency level is ONE.

Comment: Yes, the default csqlsh consistency level is ONE. It is a client side setup. You need to check your spring client and set an appropriate value there, too. It really depends on your usecase and based on an error message it is impossible to tell.